# how to add the radio button intead of checkbox in tableselect drupal 7

Tags: forms

How can I add the yes/no radio button instead of check box in the table-select module?

Answer (score 1):

As per [Adding checkboxes to a table](https://drupal.org/node/945102#drupal7), you need to set `#multiple` on the element:

```
$form['table'] = array(
  '#type' => 'tableselect',
  '#header' => $header,
  '#options' => $options,
  '#multiple' => FALSE,
);
```

Comment: Thanx Clive. The thing is i want Yes/No options radiobuttons instead of the checkbox rest it should remain multiple selection.